# C# - capture the webcam and adding the frames

Tags: c#, webcam

I  looked for frequently and didn't find any example I needed. What I need is to capture webcam video and change it by adding my own frames (in other words, overlay images)  using C# and frame for it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a free solution, you could search for open source libraries such as ffmpeg-sharp, but I myself couldn't find any of them that supports image overlay over video.

There are commercial libraries that do this but they're not free. From these I tried leadtools which has a filter that can overlay image with transparency over a video stream. There is a sample project in this forum post:
http://support.leadtools.com/cs/forums/22836/ShowPost.aspx#22836